# How to start docker desktop with a cli command on macOS without showing dashboard?

Tags: macos, docker, hide, desktop, dashboard

I have a cli command that starts the Docker desktop environment on macOS whenever it's not running.

```
open --background -a Docker
```

It used to work without the docker dashboard popup at startup (showing only in the top bar as an icon, which was fine) but since the version 2.4.0.0 update it does not hide anymore? I tried adding the --hide option like this:

```
open --hide --background -a Docker
```

But it did not work. Is there anyway to disable or hide the Docker dashboard popup when starting?

Answer (score 6):

Docker Dashboard -> Settings -> General -> remove tick on "Open Docker Dashboard at startup"